# How should proguard be configured with Google Play Services

Tags: android, maven, google-play-services, proguard, aar

I have standard problem with Multiple dex files:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$array;

I am developing aar library that have dependency to google play services (version: 9.4.0) in maven. There are no problems when running proguard but dex issue appear when I add this library to an application.

Proguard file (base on Android-proguard):

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}


-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keep class **.R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep public class * {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**

-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}
```

Maven pom:

```
...
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
            <artifactId>play-services-wallet</artifactId>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>6.0_r1</version>
        </dependency>
...
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                            <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                            <release>true</release>
                            <sdk>
                                <platform>21</platform>
                            </sdk>
                            <proguard>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                                <config>
                                    ${project.basedir}/proguard-android-pay.cfg
                                </config>
                             </proguard>
                            <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                        </configuration>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                    </plugin>
```

Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'

    compile('problematic.library.sdk:library-with-google-play-services:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your app level `build.gradle` file. I think you used different version of `com.google.gms.google-services`

Comment: This is not an issue with Proguard. Since google services 6.5., if you're using single modules from play services you should not the use whole play services as dependency simultaneously. Solution is to select only those services that you need instead of whole package. I am not quite confident on maven build script syntax but from the looks of it, looks like you have included only the artifact you need in your .aar generating buils. Can you review your application build script along on that line again because that's definitely the issue.

Comment: Added gradle build @Dibzmania -> I added in maven (pom) only part that is needed (not all google services)

Comment: Can you try excluding the V7 support library from library compile block of your problematic library. I am not sure why are you excluding the v4 support library while you don't have a dependency on it in the app